# How to extract text under specific heading from a text file using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Need to extract only a particular block of data.

I'm trying to display candidates Experience summary. I used the below code to do so, but it is extracting the texts from Experience summary till the end. How can I stop this to capture only Experience summary?

Below is my Code:

```
import os 

with open('abcd.txt','r',encoding='latin-1') as infile: #open("E:/cvparser/shanbhag.txt",'w', encoding='latin-1')as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Experience Summary:":
            copy = True
        elif copy:
            print(line)
```

This is my text file(abcd.txt):

```
Name : XYZ
Email: ABCD@gmail.com
Phone:  1234567890
______________________________________________________________________________    
Objective:
To work in a challenging and stimulating environment that fulfills my creative satisfaction as a User Interface Web Designer and to grow in the organization as a team player.
Experience Summary:
·   4+ Years of experience in Software developing and database development.
·   Experienced in Moodle Development.
·   Had 2+ Years of experience in MySQL database, Cassandra database, python , project designing, project workflow, Image recognition using IBM Watson, voice recognition, SEO on increasing page ranking.
·   Had work experience of 2 years as SAP ABAP developer.
·   Experience in developing and configuring Moodle tool.
·   Good experience in python backend code development (in machine learning, deep learning, neural networks, TensorFlow Framework).
·   Experience in database designing and er diagrams.
·   Experience in MySQL, Cassandra databases.
·   Experience in sql queries.
·   Good knowledge on Boardwalk database and block chain.
·   Experience in developing Chat-Bots conversations using API.ai.

 Web Technologies:


Web Technologies    :  HTML, jQuery , CSS, Ruby on rails, Python
Databases       : MySQL, Cassandra, Boardwalk database
Languages       : SAP Abap, Basic understanding of Webdynpro
Others          : IBM Watson, AJAX, Voice recognition using API.ai and WIT.ai, Google Tensor-flow.

Professional Experience:

·   Working at Ambertag Analytics Pvt ltd as Senior Software Engineer since March 2016 – till now.

·   Worked at Vernasoft consultancy Pvt ltd as SAP ABAP Consultant since June 2013 to June 2015 .

·   Job Profile: Currently working on automating Image classifier using Google tensor flow  ,working on designing the chat-bots for e-commerce websites and Moodle Framework implementation for Educational systems.


Portfolio:
PROJECTS

Project 1

Project   :Materiall - Implementation
Duration: March 2016 – June 2017
Type       : Web Based Application (Mysql, Ruby on Rails)
Role       : Software developer
Client     : Materiall

Description: Materiall is the furniture site and  was founded out of a passion for finding a better way to browse products on-line, to help find your global maximum, and to make search more transparent and interactive. 

Responsibilities: 

·   Web developer:- Developed the platform for classifying the attributes(like,style) of any e-commerce products and saving the data to the database.
·   . If suppose the admin rejects the image, that image will be back to the developer database.

·   Html&Css:- Designed the website using HTML & CSS. My role is to create the web pages and including the given text and images to the website. Doing perfect alignments and making the website looking much better.

·   Migrate the data from test database to production database by using Perl script commands.

·   Voice recognization:- Developed a Chat-Bot conversation and handling the conversation failure cases using API.ai services. Creation of the chat-bot mind-maps.


ACADEMICS
BTECH ,Computer science engineering from JNTUA (2009 -2013)
12th from Sri chaitanya college ,Hyderabad (2007-2009)
10th from Sister Stanislas English medium school, Kurnool (2007) 


PERSONAL DETAILS

Date of Birth:  15th Mar 1992
Languages known: English, Hindi, Telugu
Fathers Name: Suryanarayana.L
Passport details:- Under process
```

Comment: `elif line.strip() == "Web Technologies:": copy = False`

Comment: is `Experience summary` subitem always starts with `·` (middle-dot) ?

Comment: No. In this case it is Web Technologies, but when I use different resume there might be some other details. So I cannot declare copy =False when its Web Technologies. Is there any other way? @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Not Necessarily. Its just an example I have posted. I am trying to extract data from resume which is in text format. @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0):

With specific conditional:

```
with open('abcd.txt') as f:
    exp_summary_flag = False
    exp_summary = ''
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Experience Summary:'):
            exp_summary_flag = True
        elif exp_summary_flag:
            exp_summary += line
            if not line.strip(): break

print(exp_summary)
```

The output:

```
·   4+ Years of experience in Software developing and database development.
·   Experienced in Moodle Development.
·   Had 2+ Years of experience in MySQL database, Cassandra database, python , project designing, project workflow, Image recognition using IBM Watson, voice recognition, SEO on increasing page ranking.
·   Had work experience of 2 years as SAP ABAP developer.
·   Experience in developing and configuring Moodle tool.
·   Good experience in python backend code development (in machine learning, deep learning, neural networks, TensorFlow Framework).
·   Experience in database designing and er diagrams.
·   Experience in MySQL, Cassandra databases.
·   Experience in sql queries.
·   Good knowledge on Boardwalk database and block chain.
·   Experience in developing Chat-Bots conversations using API.ai.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect..!! It worked for the above example, but when I changed my text file it doesn't seems working.

Here is my text file:

```
abcd
Enthusiastic Data science and Analyst

zxy@gmail.com

+91 1234567890

Flat No. -6, 6 Pocket Building, near Trimurti Chowk,
Dhankawadi, Pune-(411043), INDIA

An achievement-driven and result oriented individual, I am here for an opportunity to utilize my skills and showcase my talent and
secure a responsible position in the ﬁrm.

EDUCATION

SKILLS

Result: 65%

Class 12
Institution: Him Academy Public School,
Himachal Pradesh
2012 – 2014

Result: 86%

Bachelors(B.tech)
Institution: Bharati Vidyapeeth College of
Engineering, Pune
2015 – Present

Electronics and
Telecommunication: Result:
8.0(Sem-7th)

Diploma(Network Security)
Institution: Bharati Vidyapeeth College of
Engineering, Pune
2015 – Present

Result: 66%

ADDITIONAL EXPERIENCE

Deputy Joint Secretary
BVPCOE Network Security Group
2017
It is a team of students who work and bring technical and creative skills
together to organize events.

Sports Head
BVPCOE Electronics and Telecommunication
Student Association
2017 – Present
It is an association which helps to bring out the talent of students which
organizes and take part in National Level fests in diﬀerent colleges.

Volunteer
NSG (Network Security Group)
2016 – 2017
Volunteering in Publicity and creativity team of Network Security Group
for Cybercon 2017 technical event.

Volunteer
ETSA (Electronics and Telecommunication
Association)
2016 – 2017
Creativity and Sports event volunteering in inter-department
competition like DropShot , Basketball and in Bharatiyam national level
fest.

Data Analytics and Visualization

R programming

Descriptive Statistics

Inferential Statistics

Machine Learning

MS-Excel

Python

Ethical Hacking

TRAINING

Marsian Technologies (11/2017 – 03/2018)
Data Science and Professional course.

CERTIFICATES

Data Science Professional Course
(11/2017 – 03/2018)

LANGUAGES

English & Hindi

INTERESTS

Cybernaut

Video Games

HIIT
```

Here I am not able to extract Additional Experience. @RomanPerekhrest